# Why the “getPassenger()” method in the below for loop can be called directly without creating an object first？

Tags: java

Why the “getPassenger()” method in the below for loop 
can be called directly 
without creating an object first？

```
package org.airline.reservations;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Database {

//fields
private ArrayList<Seat> seats;
private ArrayList<Flight> flights;
private ArrayList<Ticket> tickets;
private ArrayList<Passenger> passengers;

//constructor
public Database() {
    seats = new ArrayList<Seat>();
    flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();
    tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
    passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
}
//get the seats arraylist
public ArrayList<Seat> getSeats() {
    return seats;
}
//get the flights arraylist
public ArrayList<Flight> getFlight() {
    return flights;
}
//get the tickets arraylist
public ArrayList<Ticket> getTicket() {
    return tickets;
}
//get the passengers arraylist
public ArrayList<Passenger> getPassenger() {
    return passengers;
}
//add an Seat object to the seats arraylist
public void addSeat(int seatNumber) {
    seats.add(new Seat(seatNumber));

}
//get the seats arraylist
public ArrayList<Seat> getSeat() {
    return seats    ;
}

//this method add a Flight object to the flights arraylist
public void addFlight(String departureCity, String arrivalCity, int flightNumber) {

    flights.add(new Flight(departureCity, arrivalCity, flightNumber));

}

//this method add a Passenger object to the passengers arraylist , if the 
//passenger object already exists in the passengers arraylist return true 
//else reture false
```

my question is why the “getPassenger()” method in the below for loop can be called directly without creating an object first？

```
public boolean addPassenger(String passengerName) {
        boolean passengerExists = false;
        for (Passenger item : getPassenger()){
            if (passengerName.equals(item.getName())) {
                passengerExists = true;

            } 
        }
        passengers.add(new Passenger(passengerName));
        return passengerExists;
}
```

Comment: **This** is really basic stuff.

Comment: because it´s called on an instance of this class `Database`

Comment: Because `addPassenger()` resides in the same `Database` class of which the `passengers` is member of.

Comment: You don't need to. Because they are in the same Class (blueprint) of the so called Database object. In short they both are instance_level methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addPassenger()` itself is an *instance-level* method. So, you need to call it using an instance of `Database`. The same instance (also know as `this` ) is *implicitly* passed to other instance method calls.

Comment: so `for (Passenger item : getPassenger())` equals `for (Passenger item : this.getPassenger())` and the later is more clear?

Comment: @jcy - In a general sense , yes

Answer (score 0):

You have created an instance already: it is the instance on which you are calling `addPassenger`.

Comment: so  because the getPassenger() method is inside the addPassenger() method , i can call the getPassenger() method directly without the keyword "this"?

Comment: @jcy : Nop. Because they both are instance-level methods of the class Database itself is the reason for this.